# required difference keys from 2 array in php

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have following 2 arrays,

1)

```
Array
    (
        [109] => 0
        [112] => 10
        [113] => 0
        [110] => 0
    )
```

2)

```
Array
    (
        [112] => 10.00
    )
```

now i want output as

Array

```
(
        [109] => 0
        [113] => 0
        [110] => 0
    )
```

here [112] i dont want because it is same i want difference. i used `array_diff(arr1,arr2);` but i am getting [112]. how can i get rid of 112. since 10 and 10.00 is same in value

Comment: check the result here, there is no index(112) occur http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be32d36f92cc6e1a66063f0dbbbe1bf7a8617edc

Comment: array_diff should work, yes.

Comment: i think you are doing some thing wrong. you should add your code in the question

Answer (score 2):

That's because your values are string. So 10 and 10.00 are different values. Do change all values to int or float.

```
$arr1 = array_map('floatval', $arr1);
$arr2 = array_map('floatval', $arr2);

array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: the op wants to calculate the difference in the `array_keys`, not the values

Comment: In the question, he is mentioning the values are same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) function. For example:

```
$arr1 = [
    109 => 0,
    112 => 10,
    113 => 0,
    110 => 0
];

$arr2 = [
    112 => 10.00
];


print_r(array_diff_key($arr1, $arr2));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [109] => 0
    [113] => 0
    [110] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a variation of `array_diff` which is `array_diff_key`which will compute difference on keys rather than the values.

```
$result = array_diff_key($array1,$array2)
var_dump($result);
```

[doc_link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)